# Reactstrap: Getting attribute value from navItem resolves to null sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, mern, reactstrap

I have this component:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tab_to_display: null,
    };
    this.onTabSelected = this.onTabSelected.bind(this);
  }

  onTabSelected(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // tab_name is logged as null sometimes
    // And this happens randomly with different tabs
    const tab_name = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    console.log(
      " ~ file: ParentComponent.js ~ line 52 ~ ParentComponent ~ onTabSelected ~ tab_name",
      tab_name
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { tab_to_display } = this.state;

    const tab_items_info = [
      {
        tab_name: "tab_1",
        icon: "fa fa-users",
        component: <TabConentComponent1 />,
      },
      {
        tab_name: "tab_2",
        icon: "fa fa-users",
        component: <TabConentComponent2 />,
      },
      {
        tab_name: "tab_3",
        icon: "fa fa-users",
        component: <TabConentComponent3 />,
      },
      {
        tab_name: "tab_4",
        icon: "fa fa-users",
        component: <TabConentComponent4 />,
      },
      {
        tab_name: "tab_5",
        icon: "fa fa-users",
        component: <TabConentComponent5 />,
      },
    ];

    return (
      <Container className="container-fluid">
        <div className="nav-tabs-navigation">
          <div className="nav-tabs-wrapper">
            <Nav role="tablist" tabs>
              {/* 
                    Sometimes when I click on a tab
                    Its value attribute is detected as null
                    Inside onTabSelected */}
              {tab_items_info.map((nav_item) => {
                const { tab_name, icon } = nav_item;

                return (
                  <NavItem className="cursor-pointer">
                    <NavLink
                      value={tab_name}
                      onClick={this.onTabSelected}
                      className={tab_to_display == tab_name ? "active" : ""}
                    >
                      <i className={icon} />
                    </NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                );
              })}
            </Nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <TabContent activeTab={tab_to_display}>
          {tab_items_info.map((tab_item) => {
            const { tab_name, component } = tab_item;
            return (
              <TabPane tabId={tab_name} id={tab_name}>
                {component}
              </TabPane>
            );
          })}
        </TabContent>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on a tab sometimes its value, is correctly resolved in `onTabSelected`:

```
  <NavLink
                      value={tab_name}
                      onClick={this.onTabSelected}
                      className={tab_to_display == tab_name ? "active" : ""}
                    >
                      <i className={icon} />
                    </NavLink>
```

Sometimes, it is resolved to null:

```
 ~ file: InstitutionPage.js ~ line 52 ~ InstitutionPage ~ onTabSelected ~ tab_name null
```

And this happens randomly. So I have no idea what's causing it.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating this it turns out the problem is with using an icon inside the `NavLink`:

```
  <NavLink
                    className="cursor-pointer test-border"
                    value="test"
                    onClick={this.onTabClicked}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-book" />
                  </NavLink>
```

Using a text solves this problem:

```
<NavLink
                className="cursor-pointer test-border"
                value="test"
                onClick={this.onTabClicked}
              >
                test
              </NavLink>
```

Not sure though why would an icon cause this.